# How to fix ajax when fetching the data without load or refresh? CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My problem is I can already fetch the data but I still need to refresh the page when a data is inserted from the backend. in the front end is there where I uses ajax.

So I need a solution where when the data is inserted then the page should stay as it is and the data must be fetched without load or refresh

So here is my view

I have a div, so everytime a data is inserted the number must be incremented without refresh

```
<div id="count"></div>
```

My script

```
<script>
$(function(){

        showAllPosts();
        //function
        function showAllPosts(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>students/showAllPosts',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){

                    var count = '';
                    count += '<p>'+data.length+'</p>';
                    $('#showdata').html(count);

                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not get Data from Database');
                }
            });
        }
});
</script>
```

In my Controller

```
public function showAllPosts(){
    $result = $this->student_model->showAllPosts();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

And my Model

```
public function showAllPosts(){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('classes');
    $this->db->join('posts', 'classes.group_id = posts.activity_id');
    $this->db->where('classes.student_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: Why do you want ajax to be set to async: false,? AJAX= "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML"

Comment: @Vickel - should I change it? or change it to cache?

Comment: just don't write that line, it defaults to "async:true" read [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @Vickel - hello I've tried it but the data still not fetching, it does fetched after reload

Comment: you need to provide more informations here - where and when do you save your new data because what does _I have a div, so everytime a data is inserted the number must be incremented without refresh_ mean ?

Comment: If you want to show data in `id="count"` and the data is not empty then you'll have to use `$('#count').html(count);`